# Selecting an option from dropdown menu to fill textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have filled the drop down menu with names from the my UserData database. I am currently trying to select an users name to make their user details appear in the textboxes, however when I try to select an option from the dropdown menu, the first option always appears in the textboxes I was wondering if anybody could see a problem in my code?

```
protected void BtnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataReader reader;
    String connString = ConfigurationManager
        .ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email FROM UserData " + 
        "WHERE TeacherID = @TeacherID", conn);

    comm1.Parameters.Add("@TeacherID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    comm1.Parameters["@TeacherID"].Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        reader = comm1.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            txtFirstName.Text = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
            txtLastName.Text = reader["LastName"].ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = reader["Email"].ToString();
        }

        reader.Close();         
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        dbErrorLabel.Text = ("Error in retrieval"+ ex.StackTrace);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What are you trying to accomplish? Please be specific

Comment: When I try to select an option, the error message in my catch block is returned and the textboxes remain empty. I am trying to select a user from my database by selecting their name in the dropdown box. When I select their name their first name, last name and email should appear in the textboxes. I will later allow an admin to update or delete these details

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Change your Catch to `Catch (Exception ex)` and then in the block modify the line to `dbErrorLabel.Text = ex.Text`.

Comment: Your catch needs to be catch(Exception ex) then put a breakpoint in the catch block and tell us what the error is.

Comment: The select button now successfully fills the textboxes with the details of the user selected in the drop down menu. However now my problem is that the textboxes are always filled with the details of the first user in the drop down menu

Answer (score 0):

Try altering your code slightly like this and then you will find it easier to debug. Check what value you're getting for the selected value (is it what you expect) and also what the content of the actual exception is that you're getting.

This should help you to work out what's going on.

```
protected void BtnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataReader reader;
    String connString = ConfigurationManager
        .ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email FROM UserData " + 
        "WHERE TeacherID = @TeacherID", conn);

    var selectedValue = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
    var selected = int.Parse(selectedValue);                

    comm1.Parameters.Add("@TeacherID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    comm1.Parameters["@TeacherID"].Value = selected;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        reader = comm1.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            txtFirstName.Text = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
            txtLastName.Text = reader["LastName"].ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = reader["Email"].ToString();
        }

        reader.Close();         
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        dbErrorLabel.Text = ("Error in retrieval " + ex.StackTrace );
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```